# Getting number in floating format from database in my App

Tags: java, database, android-studio

I use EditText for a form in my app , and asking user to enter a number then after getting the number (double) from EditText storing it on the database , everything works fine till here, but when i want to show the number in my app it shows in floating format e.g if user enter 32453905 in my app i get 32453905.0 which i really don't need how to fix it.

code to  convert text to double

```
private double textToDouble(String number)
{
    if (number != null && number.length() > 0)
        return Double.parseDouble(number);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

code for getting number from database

```
   String stringNumber = Double.toString(user.getNumber());
    editTextNationalNumber.setText(stringNumber);
```

Comment: `double / DOUBLE` - floating point, always an approximation, `BigDecimal / DECIMAL` - fixed point. `new BigDecimal("123")` would give a "scale", 0 decimals.

Comment: @JoopEggen BigInteger seems to be a good choice , I used it but still not getting the number in the format i want e.g when i enter  2147483647 , I get 2.147483647E9 any help?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal.toPlainString()`. Its `toString()` will also use the scientific notation with E.

Answer (score 1):

Since you allow users to enter double value numbers you need to check if the number has any digits after the decimal point so:

```
double d = user.getNumber();
String text = "";
if (d % 1 == 0) {
    text = Integer.toString((int)d);
} else {
    text = Double.toString(d);
}
editTextNationalNumber.setText(text);
```

Comment: what if the number is beyond the range of int , typecasting gives me the value 0

Comment: Just use BigInteger.toString instead of Integer

Answer (score 0):

@zolfa have to tried user.getNumber().toString() or String.valueOf(user.getNumber());

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers dont have to be put in as text you can use the Scanner function of java

```
Import java.util.Scanner;
```

And to get input use

```
double number = in.nextDouble();
```

The value will get stored in number as a double

A double will always return a decimal number. So try to use type casting like

```
(int) variabeleAsDouble
```

Then your program will accept decimals, but rounds it to a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
//number without decimals
int number = (int) user.getNumber();
String stringNumber = Integer.toString(number);
```

If user can also enter decimal values, than you can handle both like this:

```
//number without decimals
double doubleNumber = user.getNumber();
int intNumber = (int) doubleNumber;

String stringNumber;

if(intNumber == doubleNumber)
    stringNumber = Integer.toString(intNumber);
else
    stringNumber = Double.toString(doubleNumber);
```

This will ensure that you will display correct decimal value if user enters one.